# How to rotate the x-axis label of bar-chart in android?

Tags: android

I'm using chart engine library to draw bar chart. X-Axis label has text values and it required more space. How can I tilt the x-axis values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
renderer.setXLabelsAngle(ANGLE);
```

Where `ANGLE` is your desired text angle?